# call functions with a='str' format python

Tags: python

i want to create a function that when i want to call for it its arguments can be unlimited and have a specified type like '''a='test1',b='test2'''',etc. and then i split the '=' and work with the 'a''s and 'testi's. the following code is not useful.

```py
def check(*arg):
    c=[]
    for i in arg:
        if not'=' in i:
            c.append(i)
    
check(saeed='1234567', ab='afj$L12')
```

it says:

```
TypeError: check() got an unexpected keyword argument 'saeed'
```

Comment: your are looking for dict unpacking. Just replace `*args` with `**kwargs`

Comment: Your code has several syntax errors. Please [edit] to fix the whitespace problems.

Comment: notice that i need to work with the names of arguments for exp here with 'saeed ' and 'ab'

Comment: tnx it worked with **kwargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
def check(**kwargs):
    c=[]
    for i in kwargs.values():
        if not '=' in  i:
             c.append(i)
```

You could replace it with this one liner:

```
def check(**kwargs):
    return [i for i in kwargs.values() if not '=' in  i]
```